# Jquery click does not working with dynamically added link

Tags: jquery, dynamic, click

I'm facing an issue with a dynamically added link.

HTML

```
<button class="click-me">Click me</button>
<br><br><br>
<div class="dyanmic-link"></div>
```

JQuery

```
//Embedding a link dynamically
$('.dyanmic-link').html("<a href='www.google.com' class='dynamic-link'>Click Dynamically </a>");

//Click on a button 
$('.click-me').click(function(){
  $('.dynamic-link').click(); //Not working
  $('.dynamic-link').trigger( "click" ); //Not working
});
```

JSfiddle :- https://jsfiddle.net/e9ue227c/30/

Comment: check browser console for error and paste the same in question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I updated the question with JSfiddle link.

Comment: do you want that when click on `'.click-me')` the `'.dynamic-link'` will clicked ... why do you insert `$('.dynamic-link').click();` to the `'.click-me'` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click()` doesn't directly work on a jQuery wrapped anchor. You need to pull out the [native DOM object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/) before you trigger a click. Replace this:

```
$('.dynamic-link').click(); //Not working
```

with this:

```
$('.dynamic-link')[0].click();
```